# WP App crashes after an update

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I've got a small problem that im not quite sure how to solve, i perform regular updates to my windows phone apps in C#, the problem im having is sometimes when some people update the app it wont open for them and this is only a very few people. Even after removing and reinstalling the app it still won't open, i can't recreate this error myself ive tried, but the weird thing is the last time i updated and got a complaint i only changed one thing a url in a webbrowser which has no actual effect to the app and it caused this problem, any advice on what could cause it, maybe isolated storage if so how or advice on how to get an error for the app.